Windows 11 shortcuts error
I just now dragged a shortcut from OneDrive to another folder in OneDrive. I used my right mouse button, dragged, and dropped, and then selected create shortcut. I see the shortcut, but when I double click it I get the error. But when I open the shortcut properties and click Open File Location, it navigates me to the folder. So not sure why double clicking produces an error. Is this a "feature" of OneDrive? all folders exist on this computer on OneDrive.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
